# Accessing the item at a specified index in a 'SortedSet'

Tags: c#, .net, indexing, position, set

How can I access the item at a specified index (position) in a [`SortedSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Unlike [`SortedList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `SortedSet` does not offer an [`Item` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132378%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

(Also, unlike `SortedList`, `SortedSet` enforces each of its members to be unique. That is, a `SortedSet` is guaranteed *not* to contain duplicates.)

Comment: Here's a feature request to Microsoft https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/4695

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That's because a [`SortedSet` has the semantics of a set](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/02/03/c.net-little-wonders-the-useful-but-overlooked-sets.aspx) and is not a `List`-like construct. Consequently, it does not implement `IList` (which give you the ability to address items by index via the `Item` property).

As noted by @DavidRR, you could use the Linq extension method [`Enumerable.ElementAt()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). However, since the backing store of a `SortedSet` is a red-black tree -- a height-balanced binary tree, accessing an element by index via `ElementAt()` involves a tree walk — O(N), worst case and O(N/2) on the average, to get to the desired item. Pretty much the same as traversing a singly-linked list to access the N<sup>th</sup> item.

So...for large sets, performance is likely to be poor.

If what you want is a unique collection that offers array-like semantics, why not roll your own `IList<T>` implementation that would enforce uniqueness, just as `SorteSet<T>` does (ignoring adds of elements that already exist in the colleciton). Use a `List<T>` as the backing store. Maintain it in sorted sequence so you can use a binary search to determine if the element being added already exists. Or, simply subtype `List<T>` and override the appropriate methods to get the semantics you want.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the penalty incurred in accessing a member of `SortedSet` via `ElementAt()`. Can you offer an answer to the question that is more efficient?

Comment: @DavidRR: see my amended answer.

Comment: In the spirit of the cost of code maintenance in the long term, many would argue that using a vendor's API directly is generally preferable to writing custom code, **when the vendor's API meets the requirements.** (Requirements can include runtime performance.) That said, one's code should certainly be documented to indicate the potential for degraded performance. Microsoft included `Enumerable.ElementAt()` for a reason...there are certainly occasions where it is convenient and ideal!

Comment: @DavidRR Yes, but I dont conceptually like `ElementAt` for `IEnumerable<T>`s since `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't *enforce* a certain order. For eg, methods like `ElementAt`, `Last` etc doesn't make sense for a `HashSet<T>`. Nevertheless, you can implement an `IndexedSortedSet<T>` to avoid the lookup penalty, but that would also mean you degrade `Add` and `Remove` performance.

Answer (score 9):

**EDIT:** An ordinary (unordered) set such as [HashSet<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) manages its elements in no particular order. So, the index of a particular element in an unordered set does not carry any particular meaning.

In contrast however, it makes semantic sense to request an element by its position (index) in a [SortedSet<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Why bother with the overhead of an ordered collection, otherwise?

That said, for a small [SortedSet<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) where performance is not a concern (see example below), the Linq extension method [Enumerable.ElementAt()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provides a convenient means of retrieving an item by its index. However, for a large [SortedSet<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) where the runtime performance of retrieving an element is paramount, consider implementing a custom collection as **@Nicholas Carey** outlines in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20691991/1497596).

---

**Original Answer:**

You can access an item of interest by its index (position) from your `SortedSet` via the [`Enumerable.ElementAt<TSource>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```cs
var item = mySortedSet.ElementAt(index);
```

**Demonstration:**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class SortedSetDemo
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var words = new string[]
            {"the", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps",
             "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"};

        // Create a sorted set.
        var wordSet = new SortedSet<string>();
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            wordSet.Add(word);
        }

        // List the members of the sorted set.
        Console.WriteLine("Set items in sorted order:");
        int i = 0;
        foreach (string word in wordSet)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}. {1}", i++, word);
        }

        // Access an item at a specified index (position).
        int index = 6;
        var member = wordSet.ElementAt(index);

        Console.WriteLine("\nThe item at index {0} is '{1}'!", index,
                          member);
    }
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
The set items in sorted order is:
0. brown
1. dog
2. fox
3. jumps
4. lazy
5. over
6. quick
7. the

The item at position 6 is 'quick'!
```

Answer (score 2):

If you intend to load the data into a set, then access the set, use `HashSet` and `ImmutableSortedSet` instead of `SortedSet`.

Load your data into the `HashSet`, then call [`ToImmutableSortedSet()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablesortedset.toimmutablesortedset) to convert to an immutable sorted set that can be indexed.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [MCollections](https://github.com/m-khooryani/MCollections) which do insert, edit, remove, search and index lookup In O(Lg(N)) time, it uses BST and stores count of sub-nodes in each node to access the item at a specified index

Comment: This is really great library I was just looking for. Thanks for sharing.